# Multidimensional array inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this Category List where I'm creating menu planner this code is working and the output of this code is given below,

```
 $categoryList=Category::where('user_id',$id)->get();   
    $meal_day=array('1'=>'Monday','2'=>'Tuesday','3'=>'Wednesday','4'=>'Thursday','5'=>'Friday','6'=>'Saturday','7'=>'Sunday');
    $meal_plan=[];
    $i= 0;
    foreach($categoryList as $catKey => $row) {
        for($k=1;$k<=count($meal_day);$k++) {$menuPlanner=MenuPlanner::where(['day'=>$k,'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,'category_id'=>$row['id']])->first(); 
            if($menuPlanner) {
                $product = Product::where(['id'=>$menuPlanner->product_id])->first();
                $meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title']=$product->title;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:7 [
    1 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => "Product 1"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    3 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    4 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    5 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    6 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    7 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:7 [
    1 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => "Product 2"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    3 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    4 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    5 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    6 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
    7 => array:1 [
      "product_title" => ""
    ]
  ]
```

But i have multiple products in the menu planner in the first

```
 $menuPlanner=MenuPlanner::where(['day'=>$k,'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,'category_id'=>$row['id']])->get(); 
       
 foreach($menuPlanner as $menuKey => $menurow) {
     $product = Product::where(['id'=>$menurow->product_id])->first();
     $meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title']=$product->title;
 }
```

So how will I store multiple products at array indexes?

Comment: `$product =  Product::where(['id'=>$menurow->product_id])->pluck('title')->toArray(); `here $product  is product title array

Comment: @DevsiOdedra: I have issue in creating key in array when i will have multiple product can you please tell me how to achieve that presently it overwrites `$meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title']` the previous one

Comment: `$meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title']` to `$meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title'][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index `['product_title']` has to be treated as an array, and in that array, the product titles has to be pushed in using `array_push`.

In this way you can have **multiple** product titles.

Look at the following example:

```
<?php
    
    $menuPlanner=MenuPlanner::where(['day'=>$k,'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,'category_id'=>$row['id']])->get(); 
    
    //DECLARE THE INDEX AS AN ARRAY
    $meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title'] = array();
    
    foreach($menuPlanner as $menuKey => $menurow)
    {
        $product = Product::where(['id'=>$menurow->product_id])->first();
        
        //PUSH TITLE INTO THE ARRAY
        array_push($meal_plan[$catKey][$k]['product_title'], $product->title);
        
    }
    
?>
```